# Correcting the X axis values of a baseline corrected spectrum generated through the baseline package in R

Tags: r, baseline

first of all, I would like to note I am new to R and programming in general, so apologies in advance for what is probably a very basic question. Here is what I tried and what happened.

I have acquired an FTIR spectrum that I converted into a csv file, and then pre-processed the data to the format required for the baseline package (to my understanding), with the header row as the wavelength and the intensity as the first row.
[processed data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ECoQ.png)
I then converted the data to a matrix and generated the baseline by using the baseline function in the baseline package:

spectrum_matrix <- as.matrix(IMCD)

spectrum_matrix

bl.IMCD <- baseline(spectrum_matrix, method = "modpolyfit")

plot(bl.IMCD)

[Generated spectra using baseline function within baseline package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxZE0.png)
The plot generated by this has X axis values that do not match those in the original spectrum
[Original spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIjct.png)
I could manually correct the axis but as I intend to process a lot of FTIR data, a way to fix this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the package but I might be able to help a bit.

I think the column names are not used at all in the `baseline()` function. Does the code below help to set the required wavelengths?

```
wavelengths <- round(as.numeric(colnames(bl.IMCD)))
plot(bl.IMCD, labels = as.character(wavelengths))
```

**Explanation**: In R it is usually the question where to look to find the right information. In this case, the authors of the package are using S4 methods in their functions. Details can be found [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s4.html), but most important to know is: when you call the function `baseline` and the function `plot`, you are actually calling different "hidden" functions based on the specific class of the object.

In your case, if you call the function `baseline` with the argument `"modpolyfit"` you are actually calling the function `baseline.modpolyfit`. If you type `?baseline::baseline.modpolyfit` in the console, you can find all the options for your specific function call. In addition, if you just enter `baseline::baseline.modpolyfit` in the console, the actual function code will be printed. Here you can see in the first linw that the column names in the matrix are deleted: `dimnames(spectra) <- NULL`.

Furthermore, if you are calling the function `plot` for an object of class `baseline`, you are actually calling the function `plotBaseline`.

Similarly, if you type `?baseline::plotBaseline` in the console, you will find the appropriate help page of the plot function. Here the argument `labels` is described, which is just what you need. It also shows the default values that you were seeing (the column number, from 1:n).